# How to write a SQL query to get the records if there is a match or if there are no matches in the second table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
apps:
id     name
--     --------
1      Facebook
2      Twitter
3      Pokemon


markets:
id     app_id    code
--     ------    ----
1      1         US
2      1         CA
3      3         CA
```

The following query will get the apps for the US:

```
SELECT *

  FROM apps

  INNER JOIN markets
    ON markets.app_id = apps.id
    AND markets.code = 'US'
```

But how to get the above records, ***plus any apps that have no markets***?

The query would return apps 1 and 2.

PostgreSQL 9.3.5, 9.3.9 and 9.4.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option with an `outer join`:

```
select *
from apps
    left join markets
        on markets.app_id = apps.id
where markets.app_id is null or 
    markets.code = 'US'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed8b6f/1)

Comment: @BSeven -- yes, it's equivalent. the key is doing the `null` check from the `markets` table regardless of the field being checked.

Answer (score 1):

As a note, you don't seem to want information about apps, so you could do:

```
select a.*
from apps a
where not exists (select 1 from markets m where m.app_id = a.id) or
      exists (select 1 from markets m where m.app_id = a.id and m.code = 'US');
```